# Moving the MySQL data directory Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql-5.6, ubuntu

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.04
```

I am trying to move the MySQL data directory to another location. Here's what I did:

```
mysql -u root -p

select @@datadir;
Output
+-----------------+
| @@datadir       |
+-----------------+
| /var/lib/mysql/ |
+-----------------+

sudo systemctl stop mysql

mkdir /data

sudo rsync -av /var/lib/mysql /data
```

I then verified that a /data/mysql/mysql directory was created and all the data was moved there.

Then I modified the /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf file:

```
datadir=/data/mysql
```

I then modified /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/alias. At the bottom of the file, added the following alias rule:
    alias /var/lib/mysql/ -> /data/mysql/,

then:

```
sudo systemctl restart apparmor
```

No errors so far.

I then did:

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/mysql/mysql -p
```

followed by:

```
sudo systemctl start mysql
```

This gave me the following error message:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

systemctl status mysql.service
```

gives me:

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-09-01 08:09:04 UTC; 10s ago
  Process: 20380 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 20377 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 20380 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE);         : 20381 (mysql-systemd-s)
    Tasks: 2
   Memory: 336.0K
      CPU: 221ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─control
             ├─20381 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
             └─20430 sleep 1

Sep 01 08:09:04 db.msrv.com systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Sep 01 08:09:04 db.msrv.com systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Sep 01 08:09:04 db.msrv.com systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Sep 01 08:09:06 db.msrv.com systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

1. Verify the existing MySQL installtion:

   ```
   mysql -u root -p
   ```

   From the MySQL prompt, do:

   ```
   select @@datadir;
   ```

   You should see the current data directory:

   ```
   /var/lib/mysql/
   ```

   Exit the MySQL mode:

   ```
   exit
   ```
2. Stop MySQL:

   ```
   sudo systemctl stop mysql
   ```
3. Verify that MySQL is stopped:

   ```
   sudo systemctl status mysql
   ```
4. Copy the data to the new location:

   ```
   sudo rsync -av /var/lib/mysql /data/newlocation
   ```

   (or whatever volume you've created to store the data)
5. Create a backup of the existing data volume

   ```
   sudo mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql.bak
   ```
6. Tell MySQL about the new location. Edit the file:

   ```
   /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
   ```

   and change the `datadir` directive, to reflect the new location:

   ```
   datadir=/data/newlocation
   ```
7. Tell AppArmor about it: edit the file `/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/alias`  and add:

   ```
   alias /var/lib/mysql/ -> /data/newlocation/,
   ```

   to the bottom of that file (the comma at the end of the line is NOT a typo).

   Then do:

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart apparmor
   ```
8. Create the minimal directory structure, to pass the `mysql-systemd-start` checks:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /var/lib/mysql/mysql -p
   ```
9. Restart MySQL

   ```
   sudo systemctl start mysql
   ```
10. Check status:

    ```
    sudo systemctl status mysql
    ```
11. Verify that the new data directory is active:

    ```
    mysql -u root -p
    ```

    At the MySQL prompt, enter:

    ```
    SELECT @@datadir;
    ```
12. Remove backup, once everything is verified to work:

    ```
    sudo rm -Rf /var/lib/mysql.bak
    ```
13. Restart MySQL

    ```
    sudo systemctl start mysql
    ```
14. Check status:

    ```
    sudo systemctl status mysql
    ```