# Error after changing/moving mysql datadir in ubuntu sys

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I followed the answer in the Q&A [Moving the MySQL data directory Ubuntu 16.04](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/148517/moving-the-mysql-data-directory-ubuntu-16-04).

However, it's not working and gives me the following error:

> ```
> mysql.service - MySQL Community Server  
>   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)  
>   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2023-05-20 01:41:21 CST; 9s ago  
>  Process: 41185 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)  
>  Process: 41193 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)  
> Main PID: 41193 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)  
>   Status: "Server shutdown complete"  
>    Error: 13 (Permission denied)  
> evol-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.  
> evol-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.  
> evol-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.  
> evol-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.  
> evol-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
> ```

What am I missing?
What have I done wrong?

Comment: "Error: 13 (Permission denied) " suggests that you didn't set the directory permissions correctly.

Comment: how to set ? i follow link to set, its not right?

Answer (score 0):

Complete working procedure of moving MySQL datadir from `/var/lib/mysql/` to `/srv/data/mysql/`

MySQL & server version and datadir path

```
gesti@asterisktest:~$ sudo lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:        22.04


mysql> select version();
+-------------------------+
| version()               |
+-------------------------+
| 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 |
+-------------------------+

mysql> select @@datadir;
+-----------------+
| @@datadir       |
+-----------------+
| /var/lib/mysql/ |
+-----------------+
```

1.Create the new directory for MySQL data

```
gesti@asterisktest:~$ sudo mkdir /srv/data/mysql
```

2.Set ownership of new directory to match the existing one

```
gesti@asterisktest:~$ sudo chown --reference=/var/lib/mysql /srv/data/mysql
```

3.Set permissions on new directory to match existing one

```
gesti@asterisktest:~$ sudo chmod --reference=/var/lib/mysql /srv/data/mysql
```

4.Stop MySQL before copying over files

```
sudo systemctl stop mysql.service
```

5.Copy all files in default directory, to new one, retaining perms (-p)

```
gesti@asterisktest:~$ sudo cp -rp /var/lib/mysql/. /srv/data/mysql/
```

6.Edit the /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf file, and under [mysqld] add the following line (note you might have different location or file name):

```
gesti@asterisktest:~$ sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

[mysqld]
datadir        = /srv/data/mysql
```

7.Edit apparmor usr.sbin.mysqld file

```
sudo nano /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

Replace,

```
# Allow data dir access
  /var/lib/mysql/ r,
  /var/lib/mysql/** rwk,
```

With,

```
# Allow data dir access
  /srv/data/mysql/ r,
  /srv/data/mysql/** rwk,
```

8.Restart apparmor

```
gesti@asterisktest:~$ systemctl restart apparmor.service
```

9.Start MySQL service

```
gesti@asterisktest:~$ systemctl start mysql.service
```

10.Login and verify new datadir

```
gesti@asterisktest:~$ sudo mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 9
Server version: 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> select @@datadir;
+------------------+
| @@datadir        |
+------------------+
| /srv/data/mysql/ |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```